# Phrase for that which is the object of much love and hate

Tags: phrases, expressions

Looking for a phrase/expression to describe something which is so popular that it is loved/hated by many people. Examples: Google, the USA, Bill Gates I guess. I am thinking of "monolith?" I want to emphasize the fact that the thing in question continues to exist despite being controversial. Anything come to mind?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "continues to exist despite being controversial." Existence has nothing to do with how much something is liked or disliked.  Do you perhaps mean **influential**? (If you're talking about something that only generates extremes ("either you love it or you hate it") then you mean **polarizing**.

Comment: YES, that's perfect.

Comment: I'm not sure which one was what you'd been looking for, but I'll turn it into an actual answer. :)

Comment: So Google, the USA, Bill Gates continue to exist despite being controversial??

Comment: You want a noun or an adjective, or you don't care?  Please give us at least one sample sentence showing how you would use the term.  Do you want to emphasize the love-hate relationship we all have with these monoliths, or some other aspect, e.g. the can't-live-without aspect?  Or something else?  Right now your question isn't clearly enough focused for me to try to help you.  But it's an intriguing beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about something that generates an extreme reaction ("either you love it or you hate it"), then a good word is **polarizing**.

If you're looking for a word that means that something continues to have an affect on people for a long time (for good or ill), then try **influential**.